# What are these "dogbone" traces for on (1970s era) PCB?

Tags: pcb-design, integrated-circuit

I've been spending some time with some old PCBs from the 70s. I have seen this pattern on some, which are these short traces that appear as little whiskers in between each of the IC lead/leg through-holes. (This pic is obviously unpopulated.) They aren't connected to anything and are not soldered to anything when the boards are seen populated. What is their purpose? Is this a soldering aid of some kind?

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: Could they be there to block interference between the pins?
I vaguely remember putting unused traces next to ones that carried high frequency signals.

Comment: While not what's going on there: I've seen something similar in modern use that was to reduce the variation in what fraction of the copper was removed/left across the board. It has something to do with getting more uniform processes by not depleting the enchants faster in the middle of large empty areas. IIRC that's even more important when building ICs.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

That is a good question.

Olden days (for you :)), we called the PCB design process [Artwork](https://www.pcbwizards.com/handtape.htm). In order to make a "film" for the photo etching process of copper clad PCB, people had to "draw" the film. Actually a film was "developed" from something drawn on a mylar film usually, using drafting pens or using black tapes and ready made various foot prints.

Long story short, the taping required precision :-) when the traces have to pass between IC pins. So, it was convenient to have footprints with the traces already in the middle of pins, with good clearance.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it-- so these are essentially artifacts left over from standardized IC footprint masks, and as shown here the PCB designer didn't need to use them to connect traces through the pin area, so they end up in the final design just sitting there unused. Does that sound right? Thanks!

Comment: @BenZotto. .  yes. They could have been removed.

Comment: Were they usually removed? Or was it usually not worth eg saving the tiny cost on the extra silver? These are professionally produced boards (or in any case produced in some quantity) so I guess I'm a bit surprised to see design leftovers but maybe nobody thought it a big deal

Comment: Yes, @BenZotto , "left over artifacts". Mainly, it was convenient to stock common footprints more.

Comment: @BenZotto The main "art" was not only the beauty, but the electrical and functional performance, which required good piece of EE knowledge. Meantime, end-users were nothing but just amazed what "technologies" can do. Steve Jobs (spelling?) did that too at his garage, I assume. So, I would say, people were more practical. h h ...

Comment: @BenZotto It would have taken time for someone to remove them from the artwork, and there'd be a risk of them damaging the tracks around it. Safer just to leave it in place.

Comment: The footprints are, not opaque, halfway sticky like the post-it, reused sometimes. Printing was permanent... Large, (2x, 4x, 8x, even 16x) artwork gets hang on a projector screen like. Then lighted from front, and camera at the back takes picture on a large film, negative first. Some times, the reduction was done multiple times for large artworks (16x for 3 lines passing between 100 mil pins). So, whiteout did not work. In case, Exacto knife cuts out some part of the print. Draft ink, too, often scratched out. That all eventually made machines to develop CAD software.

Comment: @jay I believe the correct spelling of Steve's last name (at least the one that was likely to be laying out PCBs in his garage) was Wozniak.

Comment: I remember that my father had Letraset catalogs full of circuit boards and micro-processor templates. They were meant to be transferred onto a blank circuit board by rubbing over them with a pen. He taught me how to draw a simple board - a basic radio receiver - with a special felt pen. You would then deep the board in some kind of acid and the copper not protected by the ink was removed. You then only need to drill the holes and solder the components. The radio actually worked :)

Answer (score 43):

They're part of the layout template,

70's was before computerised layout, track layouts were done on paper and then photographically transferred to the circuit board.

If there's a need to run a trace between two pads they offer connection points for that.

pre-patterend sticky tape was used for the part outlines, and fine crepe or vinyl tape was used to lay out the traces. ([source: Altium](https://resources.altium.com/p/6-pcb-design-stats-to-make-you-look-smart-around-the-water-cooler))

[image]

Comment: Makes ya appreciate "Ctrl-Z"

Comment: for undo you pull on the endof the tape and it comes off clean, but yeah cut and paste is literal.

Comment: I remember that my father had such tape.

Comment: This, and print layout for books/newspapers/magazines is where the term "cut & paste" came from. It was _very_ literal. When I was in college, I worked for the campus paper laying out ads. I would print the text, cut out a piece of text, run it through the waxer an literally paste it (with hot wax) to the layout sheet. Same thing here.

Comment: Makes you appreciate a hell of a lot more hotkeys than just Ctrl-Z :-)

Comment: @Sixtyfive Didn't Jesus pioneer Ctrl-S?

Comment: I tried my hand at that in the early 80's.  Dreamed about being able to have software print out a good enough image... consumer printers were dot matrix and were getting into "near letter quality".

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but are such tapes and IC stickies (actual sizes, not enlarged as shown in the vintage photo) available today?  If so, what are they called so that I might find them online?

Comment: The terms to search for are dry transfer or Letraset (a common brand name)

Answer (score 3):

those dogbone traces were called solder traps. Before full automation, soldering was done by hand. It was very easy to flow too much solder onto a joint. They prevented solder runoff onto adjacent pins which would in all likelyhood short out the chips.

I ruined alot of 7476 Flip Flop IC chips back in the day ;-)